# Upload MDM App to app store like ourpact app

Tags: ios, app-store, mdm

I am developing app like ourpact. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/parental-control-kid-tracker/id954029412?mt=8

For any MDM app we will require enterprise account to set up MDM. So how could we upload app to app store ? Because enterprise account doesn’t allow us to upload app to app store. So how ourpact app uploaded to app store with MDM configuration? Is apple giving any special gateway for this kind of app?

Comment: How you know that app is with MDM configuration ?

Comment: Please check that app. Without any kind of MDM configuration you can control iPhone.

Comment: Which MDM you have used? InHouse MDM or any other third party MDM? 

Kindly for your NOTE: OurPact uses the Utility program. User must have to download that utility program to install the Enroll/Restrict certificate via OurPact utility Program while registering the child device.

Comment: You will need both an enterprise membership (to generate the MDM key) and a company membership (to generate your App Store app)

Comment: If we will do separate account than how we can merge product? Also regarding ourpact we can lock few features in child device without using utility program. We are using in house mdm.

Comment: The enterprise account is used to generate a key that is used by your MDM to sign management profiles. The corporate membership is used to create an app that connects to your MDM to request and install management profiles. There is no need to "merge" the products.

Comment: Thanks paulw for giving focus on this. Will you please share more detail on this in answer? Any documentation on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need both an enterprise membership (to generate the MDM key) and a company membership (to generate your App Store app).

The enterprise account is used to generate a key that is used by your MDM to sign management profiles. The corporate membership is used to create an app that connects to your MDM to request and install management profiles.

There is no need to "merge" the products.

The relationship between the two is simply your app connecting to the hostname of your MDM server.